# What is the Correct Definition of Eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra

> (From Wikipedia) Let $V$ be any vector space over some field $K$ of scalars, and let $T$ be a linear transformation mapping $V$ into $V$, $T:V\to V$. We say that a nonzero vector $v\in V$ is an eigenvector of $T$ if and only if there exists a scalar $\lambda\in K$ such that $T(v)=\lambda v$. The scalar $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue of $T$ corresponding to the eigenvector $v$.

If I take a $2\times 2$ matrix with real entries which has an irreducible characteristic polynomial over $\Bbb R$, what is the complex eigenvalues called then? Because in this case the above definition would imply no eigenvalues over $\Bbb R$.

If I take a finite extension $E/F$ of fields, fix $\alpha\in E\setminus F$ and define a $F$-linear map $L_{\alpha}:E\to E$ by $L_\alpha(r)=\alpha r$, then there is no eigenvalues $\lambda\in F$ for $L_\alpha$ over $F$, since $\alpha r=\lambda r$ would imply $\alpha = \lambda$.

However, I see people saying all the times that the determinant is the product of all eigenvalues, counting multiplicity. But the determinant of $L_\alpha$ is the norm of $\alpha$, which clearly cannot be $0$ as $r\notin F$.

I am confused - what is the correct definition of eigenvalues then?

Comment: Complex roots of the characteristic polynomial are called complex eigenvalues. Next time "you see" people saying that the product of eigenvalues is the determinant, ask them politely "Do you mean complex eigenvalues?"

Comment: @MoisheKohan I think I understand it now. The correct definition should be the roots of characteristic polynomial in the algebraic closure, whose product gives the determinant of the linear operator, counting multiplicity(for example just consider the Jordan Matrix.) I was taught the Wiki definition long before and I just revisited it now.

Comment: Right...........